# How to store games/apps on an SD card

Tags: apps, storage, micro-sd

I have a Nokia Lumia 520. My phone memory is full, so I'm not able to download new games. Is there any way to download games/apps to SD memory?

Comment: I have 8 gb memory card in my phone but still videos are stored in phone memory why don't say that go to settings nd make sd card as storage getter bcoz i do that bt nothing happened!!!

Answer (score 5):

Starting with v8.1 which was released to those on the "Preview for Developers" yesterday, the new Storage Sense app allows for apps to be stored on the phone, or on the SD card.

This update is due to be rolled out to all phones running 8.0 over the "next few months", and availability will vary by phone manufacturer and, in some cases, network operator.

Answer (score 1):

You can download them from the store in a SD card and you can install them from there. But the apps still need to be installed in your phone's internal memory.

So you need free space in your phone to use more apps. SD cards are useful to store music, video and photo. In summary only media content.

**Edit**

In some leaked version of Windows Phone 8.1 SDK [they said](http://forums.wpcentral.com/windows-phone-8-1/263208-installing-app-sd-card-coming-wp-8-1-a.html) will be possible to install apps in the SD card

Comment: Nokia HERE maps can also be stored on an SD card.

Comment: @akid Yes. Had forgot that.

Comment: @VitorCanova You should probably update your post with 8.1 info.

Answer (score 1):

Best option is to use your phone memory to store only Apps and Games. Do your `Storage Check` to clean temporary files and track memory consuming Apps or Games. Use your SD Card and SkyDrive to store all others (Documents, Media, etc) that you want to store.

Answer (score 1):

Go to **All Settings**-> **Storage Sense** and select your option between SD Card and Phone memory *where* you want to save your apps,musics and others. Its very easy and simple now :)